# Use Retrofit to display JsonObject information in Recylerview?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-fragments

I tried to display jsonObject in Recyclerview use retrofit library, but it only accept in the Array format. I tried to change the jsonObject to jsonArray, but the problem is the server don't recognize the json type. So now my question is, how to display jsonObject to recyclerview widget. Give me tips or idea..Thank in advance

This is my Jsonobject Data..

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "parent_id": null,
        "name": "Ionnex Sdn Bhd",
        "description": "Test Value",
        "image": "http://www.ionnex.com/images/logo_ionnex.png",
        "phone_no": "12345678",
        "fax": "123456",
        "address": "Kl Sentral",
        "latitude": 0,
        "longitude": 0,
        "created_at": "2017-08-15 02:26:00",
        "donors_count": "4",
        "donors_amount": "601.00"
    }
}
```

This is my Fragment connect to the recyclerview widget.

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
    import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    import com.baracode.eilsan.data.ApiRequest;
    import com.baracode.eilsan.donate.DonateMenuActivity;
    import com.baracode.eilsan.donate.parentOrganisation.ParentOrganisationActivity;
    import com.baracode.eilsan.donate.parentOrganisation.adapter.DonateParentOrganisationAdapter;
    import com.baracode.eilsan.donate.parentOrganisation.adapter.OrganisationAdapter;
    import com.baracode.eilsan.donate.parentOrganisation.adapter.OrganisationModel;
    import com.baracode.eilsan.R;
    import com.baracode.eilsan.model.Caused;
    import com.baracode.eilsan.model.Organisation;
    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import static android.R.id.message;

    public class OrganisationFragment extends Fragment {

        private ViewPager viewPager;
        private ImageView mosqueImage;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        //  private ArrayList<OrganisationModel> organisationModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        private ArrayList<Organisation> organisationList = new ArrayList<>();
        // Organisation organisationList = new Organisation();
        private OrganisationAdapter organisationAdapter;
        private OrganisationFragment.MainPagerAdapter adapter;
        private Organisation organisation;
        private Context context;
        private ApiRequest apiRequest;

        public Organisation selectedOrganization = null;

        public OrganisationFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        public View view = null;


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_organisation, container, false);
            recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.organisation_recyclerview);
            mosqueImage = rootView.findViewById(R.id.donate_fragment_mosque_image);

            //   organisationModelArrayList.clear();
            prepareOrganisationData();


    //        Organisation org = ParentOrganisationActivity.selectedOrganization;
    //        recyclerView.setAdapter();

            return rootView;


        }

        //here create parse
        public static OrganisationFragment newInstance(Organisation organisation) {
            OrganisationFragment fragment = new OrganisationFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragment.selectedOrganization = organisation;

            return fragment;
        }

        public class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
            private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
            private final ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
            private final ArrayList<String> fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

            MainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
                fragmentManager = fm;
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
                return POSITION_NONE;
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return fragmentList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return fragmentList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return fragmentTitleList.get(position);
            }

        void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            fragmentList.add(fragment);
            fragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }
    }

    //Organisation data change here
    private void prepareOrganisationData() {
//        OrganisationModel organisationModel = new OrganisationModel("Masjid Sultan Abu Bakar", "Kuala Lumpur", R.drawable.mosque_1);
//        this.organisationModelArrayList.add(organisationModel);
//
//        organisationModel = new OrganisationModel("Masjid Zahir", "Kuala Lumpur", R.drawable.mosque_2);
//        this.organisationModelArrayList.add(organisationModel);

        Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            selectedOrganization = null;
        } else {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
//            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
            selectedOrganization = gson.fromJson(extras.getString("org"), Organisation.class);
            Organisation org = selectedOrganization;
            Picasso.with(context).load(org.getImage()).into(mosqueImage);
        }

        ApiRequest.getInstance().getOrganisationIdDetails(getActivity(), selectedOrganization.id, new ApiRequest.GetAllOrgIdDetailsCallback() {
            @Override
            public void getAllOrgIdDetailsSuccess(ArrayList<Organisation> result) {
                organisationList = result;
                organisationAdapter = new OrganisationAdapter(organisationList, context);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(organisationAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void getAllOrgDetailsFail(String message) {
            }
        });

    }
    /* TODO
    add onClick listener to each object
     */
}
```

This is my Fragment Adapter..

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.baracode.eilsan.R;
import com.baracode.eilsan.donate.organisation.OrganisationActivity;
import com.baracode.eilsan.model.Caused;
import com.baracode.eilsan.model.Organisation;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class OrganisationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrganisationAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
   // private final ArrayList<OrganisationModel> organisationModelList;
    ArrayList<Organisation> organisationModelList;

    public OrganisationAdapter(ArrayList<Organisation> organisationModelList , Context context) {
        this.organisationModelList = organisationModelList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public OrganisationAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_organisation_recyclerview, parent, false);
        return new OrganisationAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(OrganisationAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
//        OrganisationModel organisationModel = organisationModelList.get(position);
        final Organisation organisationModel = organisationModelList.get(position);
        holder.organisationName.setText(organisationModel.getName());
        holder.cityName.setText(organisationModel.getAddress());
       // holder.mosqueImage.setImageResource(organisationModel.getOrganisationImage());
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(organisationModel.getImage())
                .into(holder.mosqueImage);
        holder.headlineLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent;
                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.organisation_linearlayout:
                        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), OrganisationActivity.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return organisationModelList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView organisationName, cityName;
        public ImageView mosqueImage;
        public LinearLayout headlineLinearLayout;
        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            organisationName = view.findViewById(R.id.donate_parent_organisation_name);
            cityName = view.findViewById(R.id.donate_parent_organisation_city_name);
            mosqueImage = view.findViewById(R.id.donate_parent_organisation_image);
            headlineLinearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.organisation_linearlayout);
        }
    }

    /* TODO
    * Implement on click listener on the recyclerview

    * */
}
```

This is my Fragment Model(Setter n Getter)

```
public class OrganisationModel {

    private String organisationName = "";
    private String cityName = "";
    private int organisationImage;

    public int getOrganisationImage() {
        return organisationImage;
    }

    public void setOrganisationImage(int organisationImage) {
        this.organisationImage = organisationImage;
    }

    public String getOrganisationName() {
        return organisationName;
    }

    public void setOrganisationName(String organisationName) {
        this.organisationName = organisationName;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    public OrganisationModel(String organisationName, String cityName, int organisationImage) {
        this.organisationName = organisationName;
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.organisationImage = organisationImage;
    }
}
```

This is MyApirequest class to get the Json Object

```
public void getOrganisationIdDetails(final Context context, String organizationIdDetails, final GetAllOrgIdDetailsCallback apiCallback) {
    String accessToken = LocalData.getInstance().loadStringData(LocalData.KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
    Call<JsonObject> call = apiService.getOrgIdDetails("Bearer " + accessToken, organizationIdDetails);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
            Log.d("eihsan", "getOrgIdDetails: " + response.body().toString());
            Boolean isSuccess = response.body().get("success").getAsBoolean();
            if (isSuccess) {

                JsonObject jsonData = response.body().get("data").getAsJsonObject();
                //JsonArray jsonArray = jsonData.getAsJsonArray("data");
                Organisation org = new Organisation();
                //  ArrayList<Organisation> organisationList = new ArrayList<>();
                org.setId(jsonData.get("id").getAsString());
                org.setParentId(jsonData.get("parent_id").toString());
                org.setName(jsonData.get("name").getAsString());
                org.setDescription(jsonData.get("description").getAsString());
                org.setImage(jsonData.get("image").getAsString());
                org.setPhone_no(jsonData.get("phone_no").getAsString());
                org.setFax(jsonData.get("fax").getAsString());
                org.setAddress(jsonData.get("address").getAsString());
                org.setLatitude(jsonData.get("latitude").getAsString());
                org.setLongitude(jsonData.get("longitude").getAsString());
                org.setDonorCount(jsonData.get("donors_count").getAsString());

                apiCallback.getAllOrgIdDetailsSuccess(org);
            } else {
                apiCallback.getAllOrgDetailsFail("Data Error occurred");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable throwable) {
        }
    });
}
```

AFTER FEW MONTH, I SOLVED THE PROBLEM..

Use retrofit library and call the api before display. So here how to call the data for future reference....

```
public void getOneOrg(String orgId, final GetOneOrgCallback apiCallback) {
    String auth = "Bearer " + LocalData.getInstance().loadStringData(LocalData.SP_KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
    Call<JsonObject> call = apiService.getOneOrg(auth, orgId);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
            StaticFunction.showLogD("getOneOrg: " + response.body().toString());
            Boolean isSuccess = response.body().get("success").getAsBoolean();

            if (isSuccess) {
                JsonObject jsonData = response.body().get("data").getAsJsonObject();
                Organization org = gson.fromJson(jsonData, Organization.class);
                apiCallback.getOneOrgSuccess(org);
            } else {
                apiCallback.getOneOrgFail("Data error");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable throwable) {
            apiCallback.getOneOrgFail("Data error");
        }
    });
}
```

Here how i called the json object in API "Organization" is the java file for each variables in api.

Comment: get JSON object convert it to arraylist and then show it in RecyclerView...

Comment: `apiCallback.getAllOrgIdDetailsSuccess(org);` Here you are passing `Organization` object but at the receiving end your method is `public void getAllOrgIdDetailsSuccess(ArrayList<Organisation> result)` which means method is having `ArrayList` as parameter. How come it possible?

Comment: public void getAllOrgIdDetailsSuccess(ArrayList<Organisation> result)...This one I forgot to remove Arraylist<> ..because recylerview need data in array format, but my json only one..How to display ? ..need to change which one json or adapter..give me hint

Comment: if i change that one ..the adapter will be in error message..

Comment: If there is only one data, i dont think `RecyclerView` is even needed. If there are multiple data than you can use `ArrayList`.

Comment: Actually it not only one data.....it lot..this one only for testing ....

Comment: If this is just test than also you should have perform it with array instead of JsonObject, so that you can test it well. Keep data as array and parse it, there is nothing extra in that

Comment: what u mean...change my json to array..server will not recognize it...if there any link for me to refer it will be better...thank

Comment: Can you add a valid json with "a lot" of data, not only one then?